# Question regarding $\epsilon-\delta-$proof

Tags: analysis, continuity

I want to prove the continuity of $f(x) = x^2$. Lets take $\epsilon > 0$ and $|x-x_0| <\delta$. I do:

$$|f(x) - f(x_0) |= |x^2 - x_0^2|  = |(x-x_0)(x+x_0)| < \delta |x-x_0|$$

Now the solution states to choose $x < \frac{x_0}{2}$ and thus eliminate the $x$. But why is that possible and how do one get to that statement?

For solving that I would have chosen a $\delta = 1$ and continued with $|x - x_0| < 1 \Rightarrow |x| < |x_0| + 1$. Both prove the continuity but I was just curious about that other approach.

Thank you very much for your help!
FunkyPeanut

Comment: I can't imagine what the solution means by choosing $x<\frac{x_0}2$ either. If $x_0=0$, then the solution asserts choosing $x<0$ which cannot be satisfied by any choice of $\delta$.

Comment: That's true. And there are no limitations for $x_0$ given in the solutions-paper. I thought about choosing $\delta = |x_0|$. But that only leads to the following: $|x - x_0| < |x_0| \Rightarrow |x| < 2|x_0|$... that is the closest thing I came up with.. To end up with the idea stated above I could choose $\delta = -\frac{|x_0|}{2}$. But that's negative...

Comment: For all $x_0\geq0$, no choice of $\delta$ will allow $x<\frac{x_0}2$ to hold. For $x_0<0$, you can choose $\delta=-\frac{x_0}2$, which makes $x<\frac{x_0}2$ and also gives $|x|<-\frac{3x_0}{2}$. So, $|x+x_0|\leq|x|+|x_0|<-\frac{3x_0}{2}-x_0=-\frac{5x_0}2$ and so $|(x-x_0)(x+x_0)|\leq\delta\left(-\frac{5x_0}{2}\right)$. But this would be quite an awkward way to prove a statement only for $x_0<0$.

Comment: Thanks! :) You are right that is awkward. I will just assume that the solution provided is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your last step: substitute $\delta$ for $|x-x_0|$, not $|x+x_0|$ as you have here. Then you're trying to make $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=\delta|x+x_0|<\varepsilon$. Now by the triangle inequality $|x+x_0|\leq |x|+|x_0|\leq 2|x_0|+\delta$, so you need $\delta^2+2\delta|x_0|<\varepsilon$. If $\delta<\min(\varepsilon/4|x|,\varepsilon/4)$ then $\delta^2+2\delta|x_0|<\varepsilon^2/16+\varepsilon/2$, which is smaller than $\varepsilon$ for, say, $\varepsilon<1.$

I also can't quite tell what your solution was going for-something that accomplishes what the above solution does in the triangle inequality step that gets rid of $x$.

Comment: Thank you for that. The wrong substitution was just a typo - I am sorry for that. I'll guess that the solution is just wrong. Thanks a lot!